# How do I batch "diff" files?

Tags: bash, shell

I have two directories "sampleWith" and "sampleWithout". Both the directories contain similar sub-directory and files structure. How do I `diff` corresponding files?

Ex: There are following files "sampleWith/a/index1.html" and "sampleWithout/a/index1.html". I want to `diff` both these files and write output to a corresponding file (say 1.txt) and I want to do this for all the files in the sub-directories. How do I do this? I know I can diff two files by `diff file1.html file2.html >> 1.txt` to get output in 1.txt but I don't know what to do if I want to diff similar files across directories. I have a lot of files that I want to diff and doing each file manually will take a lot of time. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Edit:

`diff -r dir1/ dir2/` is writing it to a single file. Is there any way I can write the output to different files?

Comment: Have you tried `diff -r sampleWith/ sampleWithout/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diff can compare files within directories recursively.

This command will diff each file in `sampleWith/a` against the file with the same name in `sampleWithout/a`:

```
diff -r sampleWith/a sampleWithout/a
```

You can diff one file at a time with a bit of shell scripting:

```
cd sampleWith;
for f in `find . -name \*.html`; do
    fn=`basename "%f"`
    other="../sampleWithout/$f"

    diff "$f" "$other" > "../$fn.diff"
done
```

Comment: The difficulty here is splitting the diff output for each file separately.  That would probably be best done by `awk` or something post-processing the single stream of output from `diff`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  You can do one file at a time with a bit of shell scripting, too. See update in my answer.

Comment: But this won't compare "sampleWith/b/*.html" with "sampleWithout/b/*.html"

Comment: Easy to do with a relatively small change: cd sampleWith. Find the files to diff with `find . -name \*.html`. set other="../sampleWithout/$f".

Comment: Ok. But then what do about `for f in sampleWith/a/*.html`?

Comment: replace `sampleWith/a/*.html` with `\`find...\`` command above. Make sure it's in backquotes which would turn command's output into an argument list for the `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--recursive` flag.

```
diff --recursive sampleWith sampleWithout
```

**Update**

To create an output file for the differences between each pair of files, a different approach is more appropriate.

1. Create a `bash` script that can be used as a helper. Call it `diff.sh`. Its contents are:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # The first argument is the file to be diff'ed.
   # The second argument is a directory where the diff output can be stored.
   first="$1"
   diffoutout_dir="$2"

   second="${first/sampleWith/sampleWithout}"

   diffoutput_file="$diffoutput_dir"/$(basename "$first").out

   diff "$first" "$second" > "$diffoutput_file"
   ```
2. Use `find` and `diff.sh` to get the desired result in the directory `/tmp/diff-output`.

   ```
   find sampleWith -type f -exec ./diff.sh {} /tmp/diff-output \;
   ```

Comment: The difficulty here is splitting the diff output for each file separately.  That would probably be best done by `awk` or something post-processing the single stream of output from `diff`.

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is the right way. The "sampleWith" and "sampleWithout" are two different directories. And my files are like "sampleWith/a/1.html" and "sampleWithout/a/1.html"

Comment: @PervySage I assumed `sampleWith` and `sampleWithout` are under the current directory. If that is not true, the script has to be updated. If the assumption is accurate, then if `$first` is `sampleWith/a/1.html`, then `$second` will be `sampleWithout/a/1.html`, and you should get the right output.

Comment: It would probably be better to use ``diffoutput_file="$diffoutput_dir/$(basename "$first").out"``, it is just much clearer I think. Also you don't have to quote variables in assignment ``first=$1``, but extra quotes do not hurt :)